# How do I enable 2 network devices on Windows Mobile 6.x?

Tags: ethernet, windows-mobile-6

I need to maintain 2 network connections on a Windows Mobile 6.x. When I plug in with the second USB to Ethernet device, it disables the previous one after about 30 seconds. How do I keep both of them enabled?